# Como realmente o XCache trabalha?

Tags: php, xcache, opcode

Como realmente o [`XCache`](http://xcache.lighttpd.net) trabalha com o PHP? É preciso necessariamente usar as funções do `XCache` para conseguir usar as suas "vantagens"? Como por exemplo:

```
<?php echo xcache_inc('count'); ?>
```

Ou a partir do momento que habilito a extensão `extension=php_xcache.so` e adicionar as configurações no `php.ini` eu já teria tais "vantagens"?

Answer (score 3):

Bem, acredito você já saiba o propósito do `XCache` então não vou falar sobre a questão conceitual aqui.

Alguns fatos a respeito: utilizei o `XCache` a muito tempo daquela época até agora ele pouco evoluíram a questão documental, existe muito pouco conteúdo a respeito. Muitos acharam que o projeto estava morto até a última atualização no final de 2014.

Sobre o funcionamento: funciona dessa forma mesmo que você falou, basta instalar e efetuar as configurações do arquivo `ini` respectivo. Mas você pode sobrescrever assim como faz com algumas diretivas do php para algum determinado script/aplicação (como você fez no exemplo).

nesse post foi explicado detalhadamente as diretivas mais comuns do `XCache` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087650/configuring-xcache-cacher